# react - componentWillReceiveProps not running

Tags: reactjs, meteor

So I am new to react and was wondering how I would create a page that passes in a few parameters and get a document according to those parameters.  However, when I try to use `componentWillReceiveProps`, I find that it does not run and I don't know why.  So can someone please explain in the simplest terms they can what is `componentWillReceiveProps`, when it runs and its purpose?  I have spent many hours on trying to read up on the react page but all of it seems like a whole new language to me since I only recently started react.  Can you also edit the code below so it works and I can see for myself how it works together with the other stuff (it helps me understand better when I see it for myself).

Below is the code for my page:

```
import React from "react";
import { Tracker } from "meteor/tracker";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

import Menu from "./Menu"
import { Notes } from "../methods/methods";

export default class fullSize extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      doc: {}
    };
  }
  componentwillMount() {
    Meteor.subscribe("notes");
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.tracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
      const doc = Notes.findOne(nextProps.match.params.noteId);
      this.setState({ doc })
    })
  }
  renderNote(){
    console.log(this.state.doc)
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>{this.renderNote()}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

is it because I am trying to render the state before there is anything in it?  It feels like I am...thats my guess at least as to I get an empty object as the doc state.

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: It doesn't matter if your state is empty at the beginning, how are you testing if the `componentWillReceiveProps` method is working?

Comment: @EdgarHenriquez No errors just a blank screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic concept is we have these types of lifecycle methods:

1- Mounting Methods: (will get called only once for lifecyle of that component)

2- Updating Methods: (will get called whenever any update happen in the component)

3- Unmounting Method: (when component will unmount)

---

`componentWillReceiveProps` is a updating method, and will run only when any change happens to props values, it will not run on initial rendering, so you need to use both `componentWillReceiveProps` and `componentDidMount` method. `componentDidMount` will fetch the initial data and if that page receive new props then `componentWillReceiveProps` will fetch the new data.

[componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops):

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives new props. React doesn't call componentWillReceiveProps with
>   initial props during mounting. It only calls this method if some of
>   component's props may update.

[componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will
>   trigger a re-rendering.

Write it like this:

```
export default class fullSize extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      doc: {}
    };
  }

  componentwillMount() {
    Meteor.subscribe("notes");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.tracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
      const doc = Notes.findOne(this.props.match.params.noteId);
      this.setState({ doc })
    })
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(this.props.match.params.noteId != nextProps.match.params.noteId)
      this.tracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
        const doc = Notes.findOne(nextProps.match.params.noteId);
        this.setState({ doc })
      })
  }

  renderNote(){
    console.log(this.state.doc)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>{this.renderNote()}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I don' get an issue but I do get an warning saying this, "Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the fullSize component."

Comment: can you show the full component (updated) are you using setState in componentWillMount or componentWillUnmount method?